# get item id from quote after custom product added to cart magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am Having Issues Regarding how to get Item Id of Custom product added to cart programatically as

All the products are ***Simple products with Custom options*** 
and i **can add multiple products with same product id and different options**.

If the product id of items are unique then i can find the item by

`$quote->getItemByProduct` and then onwards geting the item id 
but its not matching my case.

Please Help me in getting out of this issue.

Thanks in advance